# What are the default parsers for lxml.etree.parser() and lxml.etree.fromstring()

Tags: python, lxml

From `help(etree.fromstring)`, if no `parser` argument is passed to the function, a default parser is used.

```
fromstring(text, parser=None, *, base_url=None)
    fromstring(text, parser=None, base_url=None)

    Parses an XML document or fragment from a string.  Returns the
    root node (or the result returned by a parser target).

    To override the default parser with a different parser you can pass it to
    the ``parser`` keyword argument.

    The ``base_url`` keyword argument allows to set the original base URL of
    the document to support relative Paths when looking up external entities
    (DTD, XInclude, ...).
```

So what's the default parser? An `XMLParser()` instance, or a parser created corresponding to the data type (html, xml, etc) passed in?

Comment: There is a [`get_default_parser()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#get_default_parser) function. It returns an instance of `lxml.etree.XMLParser`. Why do you ask?

Comment: @mzjn Damn. I missed it. I noticed there's `set_default_parser()` in the API from lxml's documentation. But I forgot to dig it deeper. Thx.